# Does Seven Minutes have a secret ending?

Tags: seven-minutes

I noticed that if you run against a block then jump, you can jump arbitrarily high. I've tried to use this to get out of the first room from the top, instead of from the right, but didn't manage.

Is it possible to do so? Does it actually give a different ending to the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an alternate ending, have you tried not leaving the first room at all?

Comment: What I did try was waiting seven minutes in the first room... without touching the orb :(

Comment: Yeah...you need to touch that to start the countdown going.